# Delete tab automatic based on cell value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this script:

```
function DELETESHEETS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
     switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
     case "Sheet1":
     case "Sheet2":
     case "Sheet3":
     break;
     default:
     ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);}}}
```

This works perfect but what i need is to delete a tab if cell A1 is "0". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hi Roy! I posted my answer, let me know if it worked for you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
function DELETESHEETS(){

var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();

for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {

var name = sheets[i].getSheetName();
if( sheets[i].getRange("A1").getDisplayValue() === "0" ){
ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]); }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Marios, yes this what i need! 1 more thing. Is it possible without sheet names? So it just looks at cell A1 in every sheet?